# JSON feed error

Tags: json, fullcalendar

Yes - yet another question re JSON feeds not displaying.

Have searched everywhere for an answer but failed so am asking here.

This is my code to create the JSON:

```
{url: 'json-events-feed.php?clinician_id='+0, backgroundColor:'yellow', textColor:'black', borderColor:'white', error: function() {
            alert('Error message');
        },}
```

This is the returned JSON feed:

```
[
{
"id":"42",
"title":"Cooper Amess",
"start":"Fri, 02 May 2014 08:00:00",
"end":"Fri, 02 May 2014 10:00:00",
"allDay":false,
"type":"None"
}
]
```

So the I get the alert : "Error message", but how can I find what the error actually is?

I can't find any documentation on 'error:' anywhere.

I've tried changing the date format: without the ',', as a Unix date etc. but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Your start and end date times are not unix timestamps. Check out http://www.epochconverter.com/ to play with some unix timestamps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply,In the example I gave I know they are not Unix timestamps. I was saying that I had tried the various time formats.  In the documentation it says "you may specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX timestamp." I have tried them all.

Comment: Hi,Does anyone know where I can find information about the the methods etc for the error object, please?

Comment: Where are you receiving an error can you add it to this post? Have you tried copying the data your json returns and putting it straight into the fullcalendar itself?

Comment: The error is shown in this alert: {url: 'json-events-feed.php?clinician_id='+0, backgroundColor:'yellow', textColor:'black', borderColor:'white', error: function() {
            alert('Error message');  So would I just edit out all of the 'eventsources' code and put the returned json there?
        }

Comment: Just an addition, I've run my returned json code through jsonlint and it says it's valid.